# Hide div, if no rows returned from while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I want to hide div with class "product-list", if no row returned from MySQL.
My code with div is as below:

```
$sql_product = "select * from `product_detail`";
$result_product = $this->db->query($sql_product);

<div class="table-responsive product-list">
    <h5>Product Detail</h5>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_product)){     
                $product_name = $row['product_name'];
                $category_name = $row['category_name'];
                $quantity = $row['quantity'];
                $product_mrp = $row['mrp'];           
                $amount = $row['amount']; 
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $category_name; ?> / <?php echo $product_name; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $quantity; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $product_mrp; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $amount; ?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: I have already tried if condition, but how to use variables that are declared in while loop ?

Comment: Then show us the `if/else`

Comment: *...never mind;* you've graciously been given an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use IF statement as follows:

```
  <?php
    $sql_product = "select * from `product_detail`";
    $result_product = $this->db->query($sql_product);

    if ($result_product->num_rows > 0) { ?>
      <div class="table-responsive product-list">
         ...
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```